# Most efficient way to consume asynchronous HttpWebResponse response stream

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I am making a scraper in C# .Net 4.5 and utilizing `HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse` and `HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse`. In the response callback, I open the stream and get the data as a string so I can run some RegEx against it and collect the matching results.

Currently, I'm using the following code to consume the response stream. However, I'm finding the CPU spiking often on both the `StreamReader.ReadBlock` function and the string constructor which is used to convert the char array to a string.

```
private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    if (!result.IsCompleted)
        return;
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.EndGetResponse(result))
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var buffer = new char[1000];
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            while (sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                            {
                                Match regexMatch = Globals.UserRegex.Match(new string(buffer));
                                if (regexMatch.Success)
                                {
                                    Globals.AddCollectedData(regexMatch.Groups[1].Value);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref asyncRequestsActive);
    }
}
```

I wrote my application this way after finding that `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` and `StreamReader.Read` were producing poorer results. However, I'm still not satisfied with the performance. Is there anything I can do to improve this code?

Comment: Why aren't you using the async versions?

Comment: You know, I never used them before but as I was typing up my question and referencing my code, I thought the exact same thing. Just figured I'd see what everyone else thinks - maybe there's other areas for improvement here.

Comment: I do not know about performance, but your code is wrong - you will not collect all the match result ...

Comment: You test a few error conditions but in case of an error you just do nothing. That's worse than not responding at all and getting a crash.

Comment: actually i have a catch clause in my own code but this is not relevant to the question

Comment: @Bogdan actually it's perfectly ok for my applications as there is only one match per response

Comment: @JohnSaunders I looked at using ReadToEndAsync and ReadBlockAsync but found no practical use for either since in this case, the entire point of the thread is to get the webresponse string and consume it. Therefore, there is no room for idle work while waiting on the streamreader to complete.

Comment: You could be searching previous blocks while waiting for the next block to complete.

Comment: You can miss that one match. Assuming you search for text "abcdef" and it is at position 998 in the response you will miss it ...